# Netbeans Emulator doesn't start

Tags: java, java-me

When I run mobile application in netbeans 6.9.1 it shows me below error in output window.
it doesn't allow me to start emulator.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/devindia/netbeans-6.9.1/mobility/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so: /home/devindia/netbeans-6.9.1/mobility/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1646)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:787)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1022)
        at com.sun.kvem.Sublime.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
        at com.sun.kvem.Lime.createLime(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.kvem.KVMBridge.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.kvem.KVMBridge.getBridge(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.kvem.midp.MIDP.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorInvoker.runEmulatorImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorInvoker.main(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at com.sun.kvem.environment.JVM.main(Unknown Source)
/home/devindia/NetBeansProjects/MobileApplication1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:898: Execution failed with error code 1.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

I use ubuntu 10.4. 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no way to run mobile emulator on x64-jdk (in linux), so you additionaly need to install x32-jdk to compile and run your ME-projects with it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error means a mismatch in the java runtime. Are you running your code in 64 bit java runtime.  ( I guess you downloaded Netbeans for 64bit linux)

Comment: yes, there is same source for both 64bit and 32bit machine in netbeans web site. now what can i do?

Comment: I will try building from source in a 64bit jdk.